# SSH Tunneling Through a Firewall to a Cluster

Tags: ssh, terminal, osx, ssh-tunneling

I work at a university but I often work remotely. There is a cluster computer at the university that I need to be able to interact with, but its behind a firewall. Let's call the firewall F and the cluster C.

In the past, in similar situations, I would just `ssh` to F and then `ssh` from F to C. This works fine, and I can connect doing so. The problem is, unlike other firewalls I've dealt with in the past, F does not have anything installed besides `ssh`. I need to be able to get files to and from C, and I can't do so through F without `scp`.

My university offers an sslvpn for this situation, but for reasons that I and the technical staff cannot figure out why I cannot `ssh` into local computers when on the sslvpn. For example, although from an external network I can `ssh` into F and then to C, I cannot ssh into F OR C (or any other computer on the network) when connected to the sslvpn. The connection just times out.

I've thought that `ssh` tunneling might be the solution - tunnel my traffic through F to C (as I understand it). Then I can `scp` to C or from C and the packets will just be tunneled through F. However, I'm having trouble setting this up, and no guides I've found online have been helpful. I want to be able to have an interactive shell on C which is tunneled through F.

I've tried:

```
~  ᐅ ssh -f -R 3000:me@firewall_here:5222 me@cluster_here -N
~  ᐅ ssh -f -L 3000:me@firewall_here:5222 me@cluster_here -N
```

I've also tried following this guide: http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html
and this guide:

With either of those commands, the connection times out when trying to connect to m3@cluster_here just as if I was on the sslvpn. I have no idea how to fix this. Any help appreciated - and can run any commands for more useful information.

Comment: You're missing a 2nd URL in the paragraph after the example `ssh` commands. Also what is this sslvpn? Is it the name of the actual product the university uses or something else?

Comment: See this tutorial on how to proxy SSH connections through a bastion host (DMZ): http://backdrift.org/transparent-proxy-with-ssh. Also there's `sshuttle` and this thread from SU: http://superuser.com/questions/62303/how-can-i-tunnel-all-of-my-network-traffic-through-ssh

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you asked for, but you should be able to transfer files through an SSH connection:

sending

```
ssh user1@firewall "ssh user2@cluster \"cat > remote_file\" "  < local_file
```

fetching

```
ssh user1@firewall "ssh user2@cluster \"cat remote_file\" "  > local_file
```

EDIT:

There are also terminal based file transfer tools like "zmodem"

Comment: Here's the output when I try this:

Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Answer (score 0):

Read about Reverse SSH. Maybe this will help you. I use it to connect to remote storages behind NAT.